# Highcharts - categorial data values represented by distinct dots?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization

In highcharts, I have a bunch of simple, standartized categorial data. [See fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/uJz9BRJRe9am6sCf2/zew9dt8e/)

```
        series: [{
        name: 'sample element 1',
        data: [3, 3, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'sample element 2',
        data: [1, 4, 3]
    }, {
        name: 'sample element 3',
        data: [2, 4, 4]
    }, {
        name: 'sample element 4',
        data: [4, 2, 2]
    }]
```

Is it possible with highcharts to display a categorial scatter diagram, only without the dot overlap in the categories, in the manner shown below? Each value would have its own dot representative, showing distributions for each variable in that way.

[image]

Advanced feature: When hovering over a single value dot, the lines between all dots of the corresponding sample element should reappear so that the connections between the values become obvious.

Would that take a lot of deep code customization, or am I better off doing that with a different framework like [d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/d3.js/)? Thanks for ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have typically done this by adding a decimal to the x value of the points that need to 'stack', as it were.

There isn't a great (easy) way to do it dynamically that I have found, but if your values are going to fall within a fairly controlled range, it works well.

`Example`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/zew9dt8e/2/

Answer (score 1):

In case when values are the same, there are printed in the same place. But you can use http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointPlacement to move serie.

Comment: Good remark; still not quite the solution. I updated my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uJz9BRJRe9am6sCf2/zew9dt8e/1/ 

Now if the values are the same, would it make sense to manipulate the dots' css to make them `float:left;` or sth to stack them next to each other? This is dirty of course, still exactly what I want.